# "Template not found" in live-preview

Tags: templating, live-preview

I am using docker for my local webdev and am new to Craft CMS.

Currently I have a simple setup running, however, my Live-Preview does not seem to work and throws the "Template not found" error.
Yet, when I surf to the same location in my browser all seems dandy and fine.

I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple, but can't seem to find it.

Comment: What might be adding to the problem is that I am running my container at localhost:8080 (instead of 80). I ran into another error when saving a new name for my website. It would not accept the current base url in my environment variable, localhost:8080

Answer (score 2):

I needed to set the base-url to **@web** in:

```
Settings > Websites > "your Website" > base-url
```

This helps on my local docker-environment. Make sure, that your DEFAULT_SITE_URL="domain.something" is set in your .env file and that you are using the latest 3.2.x version.

Comment: Late reply, but that actually did the trick.

Comment: Cool, nice to hear :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how this would affect your docker set up, but [this thread](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/3559) discourages the use of `@web` in your Base URL field.

As the thread and @marten-brosch suggested, set the `DEFAULT_SITE_URL` in your `.env` file and use this variable in the Base URL field in the CP. For me, the live preview wasn't working because my site is secured with SSL but my `DEFAULT_SITE_URL` wasn't prefixed with "https:"